# SpriteKit - Count how many times an objects hits another

Tags: sprite-kit

How can I get my app to count how many times this object:

```
    - (SKNode*)addRock {
    SKSpriteNode* rock = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"asteroid"];
    //set the position to a random X value
    rock.position=CGPointMake ([self makeRandomXWBetween:0 and:self.size.width],self.size.height);
    rock.name = @"rock";
    rock.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rock.size];
    rock.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    rock.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    rock.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rockCategory;
    rock.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = dodgerCategory;

    [self addChild:rock];

    return self;
}
```

will hit this object:

```
- (void)createFloor {
    SKNode *floor = [SKNode node];
    floor.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame),1.0 , CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), 1)];
    floor.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = floorCategory;
    [self addChild: floor];
}
```

Basically, I want the app to count how many times the 'addRock' object will make contact with the 'createFloor' object and if the number of times they make contact could be placed in the top left corner.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a counter, use the didBeginContact: method to increment the counter and update a SKLabelNode with the counter.

1) Create counter:

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    int counter;
    BOOL updateLabel;
    SKLabelNode *counterLabel;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        counter = 0;

        updateLabel = false;

        counterLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
        counterLabel.name = @"myCounterLabel";
        counterLabel.text = @"0";
        counterLabel.fontSize = 20;
        counterLabel.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
        counterLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
        counterLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBottom;
        counterLabel.position = CGPointMake(50,50); // change x,y to location you want
        counterLabel.zPosition = 900;
        [self addChild: counterLabel];
    }
}
```

2) Check for contact:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
    if (collision == (dodgerCategory | floorCategory))
    {
        counter++;
        updateLabel = true;
    }
}
```

3) Update the label text:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if(updateLabel == true)
    {
        counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Counter: %i",counter];
        updateLabel = false;
}
```

Comment: The counter doesn't show up on the screen when I add that.

Comment: @user3578149 - did you add in the rest of the label properties where i commented "set up the rest of the label attributes here..." ?

Comment: What else should I add? This is what I've added so far `counterLabel.fontSize = 20;

counterLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0f, self.size.height/1.3f);

[self addChild:counterLabel];
`

Comment: You should add the font's color, maybe the blackground color and the font's color are the same.

Comment: @user3578149 - updated to include complete SKLabelNode.

Comment: @user3578149 - I modified the if(updateLabel == true) in part 3. change your code accordingly and it will work.

Comment: @sangony Okay, so there were a few things in my code affecting this, I fixed most of that, and I changed part of the contact delegate to this: `if(updateLabel == true) {
        counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
        updateLabel = false;
    }`

But now, the numbers will increase in huge amounts when it only hits the object once. Is there anything I can do about that? Thanks for all your help by the way.

Comment: @user3578149 - You're welcome. make sure you have the physicsBody.restitution property set to zero for your floor and rock objects.

Comment: @sangony One other question... how can I make this so the counter will increment by one every two seconds? Thanks

Comment: @user3578149 - do you mean a different counter? if so, using a timer set to fire every 2 seconds is your best bet.